# html background repeat, not fixed with css

Tags: html, css

Here is the raw code 
https://jsfiddle.net/m6mb99z5/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
            <head>
                            <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                            <title>todo-list</title>
                            <!-- this is for the tab icon -->
                            <link type="tabicon" rel="shortcut icon" href=".ico">
                            <!-- this is for google font links -->
                            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
                            <!-- this is for fontawesome.io icons -->
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <!-- this is bs CSS link min CDN -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <!-- this has to be below bootstrap so you can overwrite there css -->
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todo-list.css">
            </head>
```

## Todo-List

- X Go to potions class
- X Buy new robes
- X Visit Hagrid

```
<!-- get this from jquery (uncompressed ver.) / this must be at the body of the body to run  -->
```

I've tried everything I know in CSS, and googled issue as well as looked some up here.  It just repeats as if its just cut off in the middle of the html document. It's most likely something very simple I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it

```
body {
    font-family: roboto;
    background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-image: linear-gradient( 135deg, #FFF6B7 10%, #F6416C 100%);
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;    
}
```